# When creating a custom UIView should you create an instance variable for that custom UIView or just use the argument

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm not a full-time iOS dev so the answer to this may be really obvious. I have a model called MenuHeader and have created a custom UIView called MenuHeaderView. I have a method like this:

in MenuHeaderView.m

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame menuHeader:(MenuHeader *)menuHeader
{
    self = [self initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _menuHeader = menuHeader; // <- here's the part I'm asking about
        NSLog(@"here is menu header depth: %i", _menuHeader.depth);
        NSLog(@"here is my header depth as argument %@", menuHeader.depth);
```

In general, I usually create an instance variable called _menuHeader and just assign it in the initWithFrame. I suppose I could just deal with the argument menuHeader but I always do it the former. Is this unnecessary? Would there be any reason to just use the menuHeader argument? I think it's just stylistic and I prefer the idea of this is the local instanceVariable of the model we're showing. Is there any difference in the two different ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of an instance variable is to have it around *later*, for use in some *other* method or (if made public thru an accessor) for access by some other object.

- If you don't need that - that is, if your use of the incoming `menuHeader` parameter is purely local to this `init` method - you should *not* be using an instance variable, as it is pointless.
- But, just the other way round - if you need this incoming `menuHeader` parameter to value to *persist* for access by some other method(s) later on - then you *should* be using an instance variable, because the incoming `menuHeader` parameter is purely local and will die (go out of scope) when the `init` method finishes.

Typically the very reason for writing your own `init` method is exactly in order to accept a parameter and assign it to an instance variable, which is why we see this pattern so often.

Comment: thx matt (and btw, I have a copy of your book right next to me). I definitely should have provided more info as I do tend to use it for rendering out other parts of the UI. In that case, I would rather be using an instance var than calling those sub function with menuHeader as an argument; thx for updated answer

Comment: As with comedy, it is all about timing. If _everything_ you will _ever_ do with this `menuHeader` parameter is done _right now_ - in the `init` method, or in a method called by the `init` method - then you don't actually need the ivar; you can just keep passing the menu header value around. (Though of course you _can_ use an instance variable as a convenience.) But, if other methods called at a _later_ time need that value (e.g. `drawRect:`), then the instance variable is the _only_ way to make the value persist where they can get at it.